# item dropping system - how can i use a prefab correctly here?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

my code is pretty simple, but im quite new to unity... im trying to make it so i can drop my items on the ground when i drag the out of my inventory, but cant quite manage to do so, with a few consistent errors. I have a prefab (just learned of those today), which im trying to change its sprite renderer and spawn it. Heres my code:

```
public class ItemWorld : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform prefab;
    private Item item;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    void Start()
    {
        prefab = Resources.Load("Prefabs/pfItemWorld") as GameObject;
        //myPrefab = Resources.Load("Prefabs/pfItemWorld");
    }
    public static ItemWorld spawnItemWorld(Vector3 position, Item item)
    {
        Transform transform = Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        ItemWorld itemWorld = transform.GetComponent<ItemWorld>();
        itemWorld.SetItem(item);
        return itemWorld;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }
    public void SetItem(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;

        Rect spriteRect = new Rect(0, 0, item.itemIcon.width, item.itemIcon.height);
        Sprite mySprite = Sprite.Create(item.itemIcon, spriteRect, new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
        spriteRenderer.sprite = mySprite;
    }
}
```

My problem is i cant manage to load my prefab and use it in Instantiate without many errors...
What is wrong with my code?
Here are the errors:

(1) Assets\Scripts\ItemWorld.cs(12,18): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Transform' (yes, i know what this means, but how can i use a prefab without transform)

(2)Assets\Scripts\ItemWorld.cs(17,43): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ItemWorld.prefab'

I have tried to research but this is my last hope xd
Ill be happy for ANY help,
thanks ahead,
Gambizon

Answer (score 0):

Prefabs are GameObjects and need to be instantiated and declared as such. `private transform prefab` should be `private GameObject prefab`.

After you've instantiated the object with
`GameObject prefabObject = Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);`

You can then use `Transform transform = prefabObject.transform;` to get the transform component of your newly instantiated prefab.

Also, if you make the prefab reference in the script public, and have this script attached to a GameObject, you can drag the prefab into the inspector so that you don't need `Resources.Load("Prefabs/pfItemWorld") as GameObject`, as the reference will already be there before run time.